# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n} (-1)^nx^n \ln(1+1/n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n} (-1)^nx^n \ln(1+1/n)$

My thoughts: I tried to use the ratio test but I don't know how to calculate the limit

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n+1})}{\ln(1+1/n)}$$

If I replace $n$ with $0$ the numerator goes to $0$ but I'm not sure about the denominator.

Comment: The limit with respect to $n$ is to be considered as $n \to \infty$...

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you! It appears I was considering a completely different limit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\log \left(1+\frac1n \right)=\frac1n+O\left( \frac1{n^2}\right)
$$ giving
$$
\frac{\log \left(1+\frac1{n+1} \right)}{\log \left(1+\frac1n \right)}=1+O\left( \frac1{n}\right)
$$ and the radius of convergence is $R=1$.

One may observe that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n \log \left(1+\frac1n \right)
$$ is conditionally convergent by the alternating series test and that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \log \left(1+\frac1n \right)
$$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You could use 
$$
\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)
$$